# Saving the state of threads after execution to print list

Tags: java, list, concurrency, threadpool

I'm new to web crawlers and I'm trying to crawl a website (which is successful) and add the data I want to a synchronized List which is successful.  However after the pool of threads has executed, how can I print that list of data.

My mind has gone blank but basically if I have a superclass car and subclasses porshe, ferrari etc and the subclasses implement runnable and after a successful crawl the data is added to the superclass list.  How can I retrieve this list just for debugging purposes so that I know beforehand I can persist the data to a database.

**EDIT**

This is my main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("thread pool started");
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    for (int i=0; i<1; i++){  
        exec.execute(new Porshe());
        exec.execute(new Ferrari());
    }
    exec.shutdown();
    try {
        exec.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JSoupTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println("Thread pool exited, printing list");
}
```

**I need a list printed here of all cars added to synchronized list**

This is the superclass

```
public class Cars {

public List<JSONObject> list;
private int count = 1;

public Cars(){
    list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<JSONObject>());
}
public synchronized void addToMap(JSONObject obj){
        list.add(obj);
};
...etc
```

This is the subclass that implements runnable so can execute as a thread

```
public class Porshe extends Cars implements Runnable{

private String url = "";
private JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

public Porshe() {
    super();
    this.url = "http://www.autotrader.co.uk"
}
   @Override
public void run() {
    crawl(20);
}
```

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it. If it's too large, then provide a minimal example showing the problem: it doesn't have to crawl anything as that is irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made the list synchronized. This is useful if multiple threads access the list concurrently. And this is probably your intention: all the cars crawl the web and add their result to a single list, concurrently. But that's not what you did: every Car instance has its own list, shared with no other car, and thus accessed from a single thread.

You should create a single synchronized list, and pass this list as argument to the constructors of your cars. Each car would thus add its results to this same, unique list. When they are done, the list is empty:

```
List<JSONObject> resultList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<JSONObject>());
System.out.println("thread pool started");
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
for (int i=0; i<1; i++){  
    exec.execute(new Porshe(resultList));
    exec.execute(new Ferrari(resultList));
}
exec.shutdown();

...

System.out.println("And the result is: " + resultList);
```

Comment: Yes that makes sense.  I've voted the answer up one for speed and delivery.  Could you recommend any books worthwhile reading?

Comment: Regarding concurrency: Java Concurrency in Practice.

Comment: Problem:  How do I refer to the superclass resultList from within  the separate subclasses.  Polymorphism cannot be used because the superclass does not implement runnable

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Please ask a separate, detailed question.

Comment: The resultList is stored in the superclass and every item is concurrently added from ferarri, porsche etc (the subclasses.  But how do I retrieve cars resultList. 

How would you do it?

Comment: Have you read my answer? What does the last line of code in my answer do? It prints the result list. You realize that only references are stored, right. So when you pass the resultList to the constructor, you pass a reference to that list. So the list in the car is the same as the list you have constructed at the beginning of the method. Again, if that's not clear, ask *another detailed question*, showing your updated code.

Comment: I came back to this problem with a fresh mind and your approach worked!!  Basically I passed resultList to each thread and declared a list in the sibling classes.  Then in the main class I declared a synchronized list and I was careful to use the parent class to have the monitor and then I used the parent class to declare a print method.  So alot of lists as arguments!